# Coordinating views/dispatching events

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to coordinate several views/controls using [`d3.dispatch`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Internals#d3_dispatch) and the [Dispatching Events](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848) block to guide me. However, I've hit a conceptual roadblock. Consider the following views/controls:

- A drop-down of countries
- A histogram of number of events per day
- A list of events

I'd like the drop-down to filter the histogram and the list. I'd then like to brush the histogram to filter the list again. In other words, it should be possible to answer a question like "Show me the events for this country for these days".

The problem is that when I register filter events with `d3.dispatch`, the histogram filters itself. I know why this is the case; the histogram is registered with the filter event but doesn't know whether or not it triggered this event itself. What I can't figure out is a reasonable pattern for linking the drop-down to the histogram and the list, and the histogram to the list. Should there be a filter event for each view? Should I then register each view to each other view as necessary?

The following code snippet might help clarify the question. For simplicity, I have replaced the histogram with a button:

```js
var dispatch = d3.dispatch('load', 'filter');

dispatch.on('filter.histogram', function() {

  console.log('filter.histogram');

});

dispatch.on('filter.list', function() {

  console.log('filter.list');

});

dispatch.on('load', function() {

  console.log('load');

  d3.select('select').on('change', function() {
    dispatch.filter();
  });

  d3.select('button').on('click', function() {
    dispatch.filter();
  });

});

dispatch.load();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<html>

<body>

  <select>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
    <option>Option 3</option>
  </select>

  <button>Histogram</button>

  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to this sort of synchronization is that views (historgram and dropdown) know nothing about how to filter the data nor about each other. They dispatch events that are handled by the part of the code that created them (traditionally a controller, but it doesn't have to be so formal). This controller would then react to the events by filtering the data based on the filtering criteria —— criteria which it either maintains by itself or it can ask the views for the criteria —— and then it gives the filtered data back to both views to re-render. It's hard to answer any more specifically without knowing how you execute the filtering and the refreshing of the two views.

In addition, usually `d3.dispatch` is used in conjunction with the kind of structures [described here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), in which case each of the views would instanciate its own dispatcher and use `d3.rebind(myView, dispatcher, 'on')` to make the `on()` method available for the controller to subscribe to. For example, you can see it's being done on line 305 of the [force layout's source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js).

Comment: Each of the views has access to the original array of events, which each then filters and passes as an argument to dispatch.filter(). I didn't include this behaviour in my snippet, as I'm interested in approaches that don't couple the views so tightly. From your answer, it looks like I should investigate an MVC-like architecture: d3.dispatch seems more suited to custom events, as you discuss.